# Clarification of a step in the proof of $E|X_n-X|^r \to 0 \implies E|X_n|^r \to E|X|^r$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence, expectation, proof-explanation

I do not understand how the $2$nd step comes from the $1$st in the following :

[image]
Does the following inequality hold? $$E|X+Y|^r \leq E|X|^r+E|Y|^r$$
where $0<r \leq 1$. (If it holds then it is clear, but I do not think that it holds in general).

Basically I want the proof of CASE $1$ from the accepted answer of this question : [absolute value to the power of some positive number, is it a norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654020/absolute-value-to-the-power-of-some-positive-number-is-it-a-norm?rq=1)
Unfortunately, the author of the proof gave "it is clear from the inequality" to prove it, not caring about poor idiots like me.

Comment: It seems that the argument uses the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Prototank I'm sure I'm missing something elementary. Triangle inequality is supposed to hold for proper metrics (for example, $l^p$ metric in minkowski's inequality). Does the inequality that I mentioned below the picture holds in general?

Comment: @AndreasT the $r$ indicates converges in $r$-th mean : $E|X_n-X|^r \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: _Undelete_: Sorry, I'm puzzled by the notation of of the r over the arrow, can you give me a keyword to look it up, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove $$|x+y|^p\leq|x|^p+|y|^p$$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ and $p \in (0,1]$.

This can be easily proved by calculating [derivatives](/questions/tagged/derivatives), but I present you a proof using [convexity](/questions/tagged/convexity) and concavity, which are techniques allowed in high school [contest-math](/questions/tagged/contest-math).

The case $p=1$ is just the triangle inequality.  If $xy = 0$, then the inequality is also trivial, so assume $p \in (0,1)$.

We first prove this for $x,y > 0$.  By the concavity of $x \mapsto x^p$ on $(0,\infty)$,

\begin{align}
\frac{y}{x+y}0^p + \frac{x}{x+y}(x+y)^p &\le x^p \\
\frac{x}{x+y}0^p + \frac{y}{x+y}(x+y)^p &\le y^p.
\end{align}

Add them up so that $x^p + y^p \ge (x+y)^p$.

Hence, (using the result for $p=1$,) for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$,
$$|x+y|^p \le(|x| + |y|)^p \le |x|^p + |y|^p.$$

Use the linearity of [expectation](/questions/tagged/expectation) to finish the rest.

> $$\forall p \in (0,1], |X+Y|^p \le |X|^p + |Y|^p \implies E|X+Y|^p \leq E|X|^p + E|Y|^p$$ Now substitue $Y = X_n - X$ and conclude.